# Correlation between branchless algorithm length (Assembly) and its latency

Tags: algorithms, sorting

I have recently reviewed the new article by DeepMind (Google) in Nature named "[Faster sorting algorithms discovered using deep reinforcement learning](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-023-06004-9#Sec6)". They claim that branchless algorithms, such as sort4, maintain full correlation between the algorithm length and its latency (Table B.5 in the [supplementary material](https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1038%2Fs41586-023-06004-9/MediaObjects/41586_2023_6004_MOESM1_ESM.pdf)). Also, they admit not reducing the length of sort4 ([Table 1](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-023-06004-9/tables/1)). On the other hand, in the Table E.7 ([supplementary material](https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1038%2Fs41586-023-06004-9/MediaObjects/41586_2023_6004_MOESM1_ESM.pdf)) they show that they have managed to reduce the latency of sort4 by ~70%. What I have missed?